# Two dimensional arrays with dictionary as the value?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I populated a list, where x and y are the dimensions:

```
dpTable = [[0 for i in range(x + 1)] for j in range(y + 1) ]
```

For each value in dpTable, I need two things:

1. The numerical value of that node
2. The previous node

I thought about using a dictionary where each value in the table would be like:

```
{'value' : -4, 'previous' : 'left'}
```

But I don't really know the syntax to make the values of the dpTable a dictionary.

Comment: Just create two arrays. Much more simple and efficient.

Comment: Where would your values for your dictionary be coming from? Are you just trying to initialize a list of lists with dictionaries to fill later?

Comment: Like @busybear said, where is `-4` and `'left'` coming from in your example

Comment: have you considered using an object or a named tuple?

Answer (score 1):

The expression you are looking for would look something like the following:

```
dpTable = [[{'value':0, 'previous':None} for i in range(x + 1)] for j in range(y + 1) ]
```

Using the `{key:value}` syntax for dict comprehensions. Just change the values as necessary.

Comment: So if I want to access one of the key value pairs, would it be like this: `dpTable[1][0]['value'] = 0`

Comment: @Aetos11 yes. If you wanted, you could create a class like `class Node: def __init__(self, value, previous): self.value = value; self.previous = previous`, and use that instead of a dictionary `dpTable[1][0].value`, whichever you prefer.